# ReactJS: Large app with Nested components

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I am developing a large ReactJS app with many nested states and components. I want most of the components to be developed independently in isolation. Consider there are two components:

1. A generic **Auto-suggest** text-box (say, it suggests Users)
2. A **Form component** where I use the Auto-suggest component

At the app level I have UserStore, Dispatcher and UserActions. So my questions are

1. If Auto-suggest is developed in isolation, how can it use the app level Dispatcher? Or should the component have another set of UserStore, Dispatcher and UserActions?
2. How will the form component receive data from the auto-suggest component, if they're developed independently?

Answer (score 4):

By asking to develop in isolation, you're basically asking to use the same component in multiple contexts.  Building it to be able to work in multiple contexts is a good idea anyway, so that you can reuse your component in multiple places or multiple applications.

But to do that, you will have to pass in everything that is application-specific as props.  Notably, this includes the event handlers that would normally call your application's action creators.

You can fake your dispatcher and action creators by developing the component in a closure.  You would want to pass in the user data as props, and also your event handlers.  In a real Flux app, you would have a controller-view component that is getting the data from the UserStore and passing that data into your component.  So the dispatcher, actions and controller-view will all be faked by your closure.

Instead of using the real dispatcher and actions, you would just do simple things to update your state in the closure.  So your development bench would look something like this:

```
var React = require('react');
var AutoSuggest = require('AutoSuggest');

var container = document.getElementById('development-container');

var users = [
  { id: '1', name: 'Joey' },
  { id: '2', name: 'Johnny' },
  { id: '3', name: 'Dee Dee' },
  { id: '4', name: 'Tommy' }
];

var onKeyDown = function() { 
  // do stuff with users
  render(container);
}

var render = function(container) {
  React.renderComponent(
    <AutoSuggest
       users={users}
       onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
    />,
    container
  );
};
render(container);
```

And then your real production code might look something like:

```
var React = require('react');
var AutoSuggest = require('AutoSuggest');
var UserStore = require('UserStore');
var UserActions = require('UserActions');

function onKeyDown(e) {
  UserActions.doSomething(e.value);
}

var SomeControllerView = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      users: UserStore.getAll();
    };
  },

  componentWillMount: function() {
    UserStore.addListener('change', this.onChange.bind(this));
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <AutoSuggest 
        users={this.state.users}
        onKeyDown={onKeyDown} 
      />
    );
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    UserStore.removeListener('change', this.onChange);
  },

  onChange: function() {
    this.setState({ 
      users: UserStore.getAll() 
    });
  }    

});

module.exports = SomeControllerView;
```